# sql loop to update data

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright having a real tough time getting this working.

I have a database of employees. I am looking to better condition this data. By this i mean that many entries in the table have rows where the employee_sales_id is "?". Each employee can have multiple rows (each time they change jobs). For the same employee some entries have the employee_sales_id while others don't. I want to scan my table and update all "?" where the value can be picked out from another row. The Employee_id is unique for each employee.

DB Looks like this:

```
Employee_id  | employee_sales_id  | name
1234         | abc                | Jim Smith
1234         | abc                | Jim Smith
1234         | ?                  | Jim Smith
1234         | abc                | Jim Smith
```

You see the 3rd row. I want to fix that and update it with abc. There are many employees so i cant do this manually. It has to be a sql script. Also would be great to have it process the data on insert.

Comment: What are the other columns on this table? It doesn't seem like it makes sense for employee_sales_id to be on the table at all.

Comment: How on earth the Emplyee_id is the primary key when is not unique?

Comment: sorry. Its not the primary key. what i meant was that each employee has an employee_id that is unique.

Comment: @codeNinja can you give us a list of columns on this table? You should probably relate employee_ID with employee_sales_id elsewhere, especially if the employee_sales_id for a given employee_id never changes over time, while other values on other columns of this table will change over time (for a given employee_id). If that's the case you should get rid of the employee_sales_id column on this table and make a 2nd table (employee_id, employee_sales_id) with one row per employee_id.

Comment: employee_sales_id does change as the employee gets promoted. Other column are {email, phone, job_code, job_start_date, job_end_date, job_status}

Comment: In each group there is only one '?' or more?

Comment: in each group there can be multiple rows where the employee_sales_id is '?'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE employee
SET Employee_sales_id = ES.employee_sales_id
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Employee_id, employee_sales_Id
FROM Employee
where employee_sales_id <> '?') ES
INNER JOIN Employee E on E.Employee_id = ES.Employee_id
WHERE E.employee_sales_id = '?'
```

By the way I assume you have some sort of primary key and/or further attributes on the Employee table that we are not seeing in your question text otherwise you have duplicate rows in your table which are going to cause problems for you somewhere.

**Update**
Sorry, I'm using Sql Server. Did not see your question related to MySql.

Comment: I think that is sql server syntax,it wont work in mysql.

Comment: This did not work. Throws syntax error. {Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Employee_id, sales_Id
FROM Employee
where sales_id <> ' at line 3}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
update employees x join (select employee_id,
                                min(employee_sales_id) as good_id,
                                jobcode,
                                job_start_date
                           from employees
                          where employee_sales_id <> '?') y on x.employee_id = y.employee_id
                                                           and x.jobcode = y.jobcode
                                                           and x.job_start_date = y.job_start_date
   set x.employee_sales_id = y.employee_sales_id
 where x.employee_sales_id = '?'
```

If the employee_sales_id changes over time, then you would want the row with the ? to be populated with the last employee_sales_id value for the given employee_id where the job is the same as the current job and start date, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE employee
JOIN
(SELECT employee_id,employee_sales_id FROM employee 
      GROUP BY employee_id 
      HAVING COUNT(employee_sales_id)>1 
      AND employee_sales_id!='?')x
ON employee.employee_id=x.employee_id
SET employee.employee_sales_id=x.employee_sales_id
WHERE employee.employee_sales_id='?'
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/783fec/2)

Comment: he said that the employee_sales_id will change if the employee gets promoted from one job to another.

Comment: @ShWiVeL Yes,I`m working with his table, which is bad design.But that`s another issue.